# SQL Server 2005 Dynamic Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm very much new to SQL and struggling to learn, so I'll warn everyone up front my mistakes might very well be the obvious ones - don't assume I know what I'm doing!  This is in SQL Server 2005.

EDIT:  The code below is accidentally misleading; my_table is NOT a table, it is a *view*.  Said view stitches information together across two schemas, uses a LEFT OUTER JOIN for one of its columns, uses stuff((SELECT.....)) for four of them, and when I posted this had no column for which no two rows share the same data; I have since altered it to use SELECT DISTINCT.

I'm trying to write a function that takes as arguments four parts of a name - first, middle, last, and title - and runs a select against a given table based on those 4 parts, using LIKE.  This naive approach returns the correct results:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [my_schema].[my_table] (
    @first NVARCHAR(max) = null
    ,@middle NVARCHAR(max) = null
    ,@last NVARCHAR(max) = null
    ,@title NVARCHAR(max) = null
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN(
    SELECT DISTINCT  
        l.foo,
        l.bar,
        l.spam
    FROM my_database.my_schema.my_table l
    WHERE 
        l.FirstName like ISNULL('%'+@last+'%', '%')
        AND l.LastName like ISNULL('%'+@first+'%', '%')
        AND l.MiddleName like ISNULL('%'+@middle+'%', '%')
        AND l.TitleName like ISNULL('%'+@title+'%', '%')
);
```

The problem is that it's incredibly slow.  The most obvious reason I can see for the slowness is the very silly behaviour where comparisons are made to '%'; what I'd like is for SQL to respond to the NULL by not doing the comparison at all.  I have yet to work out a way to do this; every solution I come up with runs into the wall that is valid SQL syntax.

My question is "how do I avoid making the LIKE comparison to '%' when the appropriate variable is null?".  I am as opposed as possible to using EXEC in any context, here, because I am taking user input from the wild and returning potentially sensitive data, and I would like to be as paranoid as possible about injection - those four variables are the wild input, and I'd like to trust them as little as possible.

EDIT:  I have done speed tests and have since come to the conclusion that avoiding the extra LIKEs does not help to any meaningful degree.  I welcome any advice on actually accomplishing speed-up, and will likely post a new question soon along those lines once I've reconsidered how this is put together.

Comment: It's not the NULLs, it's the `LIKE`. A statement like `%anything%` is guaranteed to force a table scan even if there are indexes defined on the text fields. You are asking for rows with some value *anywhere* in the field. Searches like `something%` are essentially range searches so they can take advantage of indexes. If you really want to do a full-text search, you are better off using the [full-text search functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx) like CONTAINS and FREETEXT

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires a unique clustered index on the underlying view, and there are several reasons SQL Server refuses to create one for me, including my use of a LEFT OUTER JOIN, my use of three separate subqueries, and my use of DISTINCT.  I'm not sure how to refactor the view to avoid these issues while maintaining its usefulness.

Comment: What view? Is `my_table` not a table? If it's a table, *why* can't you create a clustered index, if one isn't already there because eg of your primary key? *Why* are you trying to create an FTS index on a view instead of on the table? Unless you provide all the details it's impossible to help. Anyway, the problem *is* the way you use `LIKE` to do essentially a FTS

Comment: I completely understand and agree; I did some speed tests, and removing the extra comparisons did not help.  I did not mean to come off as in any way disputing your claims about using a clustered index, and I didn't mean to hide any details - like I said in my post, I'm super new.  I didn't realize it was relevant that this was a view, not a table, as I thought they were essentially the same thing.  See next comment to avoid character limit.

Comment: The reason I cannot create a clustered index is that even when I move the view to the appropriate schema (right now it selects across two schemas, and is in one of them, so to schema bind it I stop including some information and move it to the other, since that one has more info), and drop the OUTER LEFT JOIN in it (losing me a column), and drop the four calls to stuff on SELECT (since you can't index with subqueries), the view still has no unique columns (i.e. columns for which no two rows share the same data).  See next comment to avoid character limit.

Comment: My attempts to enforce a unique column, such as using SELECT DISTINCT, met with the server declaring that I could not do that in an indexed view - and it flat-out would not let me create a clustered index without a unique column.

Comment: Put the indexes on the table, not the view. Besides, a table without a unique key is not a very good design.

Comment: Why not create stored procedure that returns this from underlying tables instead of the function selecting from view? What is your reason for returning table?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you'll get better performance or not, but I think the following Case statement in your Where statement will work as well.

```
WHERE l.FirstName LIKE CASE WHEN @first IS NULL THEN  '%' ELSE '%' + @First + '%' END
AND l.LastName LIKE CASE WHEN @last IS NULL THEN '%' ELSE '%' + @Last + '%' END 
AND ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options

1st. have optional parameter like so

```
WHERE 
    (@first IS null or l.FirstName like @first)
    AND 
    (@last IS null or l.LastName  like  @last )
AND
(@middle IS null or l.MiddleName like  @middle )
    AND 
    (@title IS null or l.TitleNamelike  @title )
```

2nd. build dynamic SQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCustomer
@FirstN nvarchar(20) = NULL,
@LastN nvarchar(20) = NULL,
@CUserName nvarchar(10) = NULL, 
@CID nvarchar(15) = NULL as
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000),
SELECT @sql = 'C_FirstName, C_LastName, C_UserName, C_UserID ' + 
'FROM CUSTOMER ' +
'WHERE 1=1 ' +

IF @FirstN  IS NOT NULL
SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND C_FirstName like @FirstN '
IF @LastN  IS NOT NULL 
SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND C_LastName like @LastN '
IF @CUserName IS NOT NULL
SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND C_UserName like @CUserName '
IF @CID IS NOT NULL 
SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND C_UserID like @CID '
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@C_FirstName nvarchar(20), @C_LastName nvarchar(20),      @CUserName nvarchar(10), @CID nvarchar(15)',
               @FirstN, @LastN, @CUserName, @CID
```

Comment: The first approach means the ALTER query runs forever, but I'm going to try that second approach now.

Comment: Fairly certain the second approach is fundamentally illegal; you cannot execute dynamic SQL inside a function.

Comment: There is no issue with executing dynamic SQL inside stored procedure. Depending on who you talk to some people just refuse to use it, other over use it. You said that 1st query will run forever, that is not true, if you pass all nulls everything will be selected. if only 1 parameter is null that only that case will be evaluated.

Comment: @SaUce There are even *more* issues than when you create the query on the client side. First, if you concatenate a parameter that contains `'` you still end up with an injection. You can avoid it but you must be carefull. Worse, SQL Server reuses the execution plan of a stored procedure, so subsequent executions will use the original plan even if the new statement would perform better with a new plan. In your case, if you provided only @FirstN for the first execution, indexes for C_LastName or C_UserID wouldn't be used for subsequent executions.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i'm well aware of "Parameter Sniffing" and that there are several ways to avoid it, the following link describes in details what each solution is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-workarounds.aspx) . In regards to SQL Injection you are incorrect, my query is structured properly as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/01/04/dynamic-sql-sql-injection.aspx) to avoice sql injection

Comment: You can use dynamic SQL inside a stored procedure, but you cannot inside a function, and that's what I explained in my post I was using.  Your dynamic SQL here seemed like it was worth trying since it only involved dynamically picking parameter names, but I just can't use it inside a function, and I would rather sacrifice performance than use EXEC and risk a mistake allowing injection, so I am sticking to functions that take user parameters, not stored procedures that EXEC user parameters.  Panagiotis is correct - the query is formed client side.